# A non-voting members of a MongoDB replica set can become a primary?

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-replica-set, database, nosql

I'm trying to set to 0 the number of votes of a replica set member via a mongo shell connected to the primary, but i get an error when i call:

```
rstest:PRIMARY> rs.reconfig(conf)
{
  "ok" : 0,
  "errmsg" : "priority must be 0 when non-voting (votes:0)",
  "code" : 103
}
```

What i do is:

```
rstest:PRIMARY> conf = rs.conf()
   ...     //the conf document
rstest:PRIMARY> conf.members[0].votes = 0 
rstest:PRIMARY> rs.reconfig(conf)
```

Where **conf.members[0]** is the **SECONDARY**'s doc conf

At this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/configure-a-non-voting-replica-set-member/%20%22%22) the MongoDB's documentation says:

> ...
>
> ```
> cfg = rs.conf()
> cfg.members[3].votes = 0
> cfg.members[4].votes = 0
> cfg.members[5].votes = 0
> rs.reconfig(cfg)
> ```
>
> This sequence gives 0 votes to the fourth, fifth, and sixth members of
>   the set according to the order of the members array in the output of
>   rs.conf(). This setting allows the set to elect these members as
>   primary but does not allow them to vote in elections.
>
> ...

But the error message returned says that i have to set priority=0 for **non-voting**, but this implicate that member cannot be a primary.

What I did not understand or where am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO. your question may fit better in [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) but make sure to visit their [Help Center](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help) page so you know what the site there is about

Comment: can you post your config file or alteast the config section for member 4 and 5

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that current MongoDB versions don't allow 0 votes on nodes what's priority > 0.  With "old" MongoDB versions you could do that.. If I remember correct, 2.6 was last version where you could do that...